# Spotipy - Bad Request following doc example

Tags: python, python-3.x, spotipy

Following the docs [here](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.9.0/#authorization-code-flow) for Auth Code Flow, I can't seem to get the example to work.

```py
import apis
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util

username = input("Enter username: ")
scope = "user-library-read"

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username, scope,
                                   client_id=apis.SPOTIFY_CLIENT,
                                   client_secret=apis.SPOTIFY_SECRET,
                                   redirect_uri="http://localhost")

if token:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
    results = sp.current_user_saved_tracks()
    for item in results['items']:
        track = item['track']
        print(track['name'] + ' - ' + track['artists'][0]['name'])
else:
    print("Can't get token for", username)
```

I get a 400 Bad Request error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/termozour/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/193.6494.30/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/home/termozour/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/193.6494.30/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/media/termozour/linux_main/PycharmProjects/SpotiDowner/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
  File "/media/termozour/linux_main/PycharmProjects/SpotiDowner/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/util.py", line 92, in prompt_for_user_token
    token = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code, as_dict=False)
  File "/media/termozour/linux_main/PycharmProjects/SpotiDowner/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spotipy/oauth2.py", line 382, in get_access_token
    raise SpotifyOauthError(response.reason)
spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: Bad Request
```

Yes, I've seen the other ideas people had to fix this issue but none worked for me:
I tried to reset the client secret, change my URI to a website or localhost, check my client ID and secret ID, and they are all fine.

What I also tried was to go all the way to spotipy/oauth2.py where I get the traceback, added a neat little `print(response.text)` and got a marvelous `{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid authorization code"}`

Any ideas or insight?

Answer (score 0):

I have to specify that I ran this code from PyCharm Professional(2019.3.3) and the issue came up from a trailing space.

When the code is run, spotipy asks for that confirmation URL you get with the code based on the redirect URI you set in the app and the code.

The issue was how PyCharm handles URLs in it's terminal window when you run the project. When you put a URL in, and you press enter, PyCharm opens the URL in the browser (for some reason) so the workaround for that is to add a space after the URL and then press enter. That works for PyCharm, but **sometimes** screws up the code. In this case, it did.

I tried to run the code from PyCharm terminal (python3 ), pasted the URL and directly pressed enter. Not only it didn't open the browser window, it also accepted the URL and let me get my info from Spotify.

In any case, the code is fine, it was the IDE that was breaking it all - maybe a good suggestion would be to remove trailing spaces after the url, if any when parsed from the library itself.

This 'bug' has been reported [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-24193) and has been marked as fixed (spoiler alert: not fixed) and will be fixed in PyCharm 2020.1

I tried running the code normally from PyCharm 2020.1 and it all works fine, so I can confirm: in my case it was an IDE issue.